# glutKeyboardUpFunc get's called without key release

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Im having a problem with glutKeyboardUpFunc. Everytime I press a key and don't release it, the callback of glutKeyboardUpFunc stills gets called, the longer I hold the key the more times the callback executes.

Here is a quick example I put up:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>


#define DEBUG 1

/* VARI�VEIS GLOBAIS */

typedef struct {
    GLboolean doubleBuffer;
    GLint delay;
} Estado;

typedef struct {
    GLfloat x;
    GLfloat y;
    GLfloat height;
    GLfloat width;
    GLfloat y_accelaration;
} Plataforma;


//save stage coordinates
typedef struct {
    GLfloat top;
    GLfloat bottom;
    GLfloat right;
    GLfloat left;
} Screen;

Estado estado;
Screen ecra;
Plataforma plataforma;


GLfloat tab_speed = 2.0 / 20.0;
GLfloat y_accelaration = 0.001;

void Init(void) {

    struct tm *current_time;
    time_t timer = time(0);

    estado.delay = 42;
    estado.doubleBuffer = GL_TRUE;

    plataforma.height = 0.3;
    plataforma.width = 0.05;

    plataforma.y_accelaration = 0;

    plataforma.y = 0;


    // L� hora do Sistema
    current_time = localtime(&timer);

    glClearColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.0);

    glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);

}

void Reshape(int width, int height) {
    GLint size;
    GLfloat ratio = (GLfloat) width / height;
    GLfloat ratio1 = (GLfloat) height / width;

    if (width < height)
        size = width;
    else
        size = height;


    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    if (width < height) {
        ecra.left = -1;
        ecra.right = 1;
        ecra.bottom = -1 * ratio1;
        ecra.top = 1 * ratio1;
        gluOrtho2D(-1, 1, -1 * ratio1, 1 * ratio1);
    } else {
        ecra.left = -1 * ratio;
        ecra.right = 1 * ratio;
        ecra.bottom = -1;
        ecra.top = 1;
        gluOrtho2D(-1 * ratio, 1 * ratio, -1, 1);
    }

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void desenhar_plataforma(Plataforma pf) {
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);



    glVertex2f(pf.x - pf.width / 2, pf.y - pf.height / 2);
    glVertex2f(pf.x + pf.width / 2, pf.y - pf.height / 2);
    glVertex2f(pf.x + pf.width / 2, pf.y + pf.height / 2);
    glVertex2f(pf.x - pf.width / 2, pf.y + pf.height / 2);
    glEnd();
}


void Draw(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    plataforma.x = ecra.left + 0.1;
    desenhar_plataforma(plataforma);
    glFlush();
    if (estado.doubleBuffer)
        glutSwapBuffers();
}


void Key(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    switch (key) {

        case 'a':
            plataforma.y += tab_speed;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 's':
            plataforma.y -= tab_speed;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
    }
}

void KeyUp(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {

    if (DEBUG)
        printf("Key Up %c\n", key);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    estado.doubleBuffer = GL_TRUE; 

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutInitDisplayMode(((estado.doubleBuffer) ? GLUT_DOUBLE : GLUT_SINGLE) | GLUT_RGB);
    if (glutCreateWindow("No Man's Pong") == GL_FALSE)
        exit(1);

    Init();

    glutReshapeFunc(Reshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);

    // Callbacks de teclado
    glutKeyboardFunc(Key);
    glutKeyboardUpFunc(KeyUp);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the ouput when pressing 'a':

```
Key Up a             
Key Up a
Key Up a
Key Up a
Key Up a
Key Up a
Key Up a
......
```

Needless to say im not releasing 'a'.

Im using linux mint 17.3 and g++, shutting off key repeat or setting glutIgnoreKeyRepeat(true), stops this issue, but also makes glutKeyboardFunc execute only once per key press, and I realy don't want that.

Does anyone know how to fix this, or whats causing this?

I also compiled the same code under windows 8.1 and the keyUp only fires when there's an actual key release.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You say that your callback gets called multiple times while you have the key down, but say that you don't want the behavior of `glutIgnoreKeyRepeat(true)`'s behavior of calling the callback once per key. What do you want?

Comment: The problem here is that the keyUp callback executes without an actual key release. 

Under Windows this isn't happening, glutKeyboardFunc gets called multiple times while the key is down, but glutKeyboardUpFunc only gets called on key release.

Comment: hey there, same behaviour here right now, did you find some solution to this?

Well rereading your post make feel like something is terribly wrong with glut like : " to have a new key down i must have a  key up before" and so glut triggers keyup ( which maychange some kind of glut internal state ) and then down again ( thanks to the state now allowing it)

i feel like IgnoreKeyRepeat just force you to reenact this behaviour by your self.